# How to make an ember component render a promise from a service

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

**How can I render UI that waits for a service injected promise?**

I'm trying to get a component to render a basic attribute of a injected service which returns a promise. It doesn't resolve the UI after the promise has been resolved despite me creating a CP on it.

I'm using this as a service because this feature lives in a navigation bar which lives longer than any of the routes and I'm trying to embrace ember2.0.

app/services/contest.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Service.extend({
  store: Ember.inject.service(),

  contest: Ember.computed(function() {
    return this.get('store').find('contest', {
      current: true
    });
  })
});
```

app/pods/components/contest-meter/component.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  classNames: 'contest-meter',
  contest: Ember.inject.service('contest'),
});
```

app/pods/components/contest-meter/template.hbs

```
{{contest.startDate}}
```

Comment: It's troubling the proposed solution is to de-promise the promise.    Shouldn't you have another reference to contest.contest()?   There is no startDate property on the toplevel service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a loaded property in the service to determine whether the data has loaded yet.

app/services/contest.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

const { inject, on } = Ember;

export default Ember.Service.extend({
  store: inject.service(),

  findCurrentContest: on('init', function() {
      this.get('store').find('contest', {
          current: true
      }).then((response) => {
          this.set('contest', response);
          this.set('loaded', true);
      });
  })
});
```

app/pods/components/contest-meter/component.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

const { computed, inject } = Ember;

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  classNames: 'contest-meter',
  contest: inject.service(),
  currentContest: computed.readOnly('contest.contest')
});
```

app/pods/components/contest-meter/template.hbs

```
{{#if contest.loaded}}
   {{currentContest.startDate}}
{{else}}
   Loading...
{{/if}}
```

Comment: For some reason I had to do: this.get('response'.get('contesnt.firstObject') to actually see the response object